# A property of piecewise continuous function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Show that If $f$ is piecewise continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and $f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$, then $f$ is piecewise continuous for all $x$.

Comment: Do you know the definition of piecewise continuity?

Comment: Consider $f(x):=[2x/\pi]$.